# Opening Astropy FITS file from SFTP server

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, astropy, fits

I have a Python script that ssh into a remote server using Paramiko module.

The below is my script

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("host", username="McMissile")
```

A FITS file on a local machine is usually opened as follows:

```
from astropy.io import fits

hdu = fits.open('File.fits')
```

I was wondering how would I open a FITS file from the SFTP server machine and store it under the variable `hdu` in the local machine.

I cannot download the file from the server to the local machine due to the storage constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Astropy.io `fits.open` method](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/files.html#astropy.io.fits.open) accepts a file-like object in place of a file name:

> **name** : file path, file object, **file-like object** or pathlib.Path object

---

A file-like object representing a remote file is returned by Paramiko [`SFTPClient.open` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open):

> A **file-like object is returned**, which closely mimics the behavior of a normal Python file object, including the ability to be used as a context manager.

---

So this should work:

```
sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
with sftp_client.open('remote_filename') as remote_file:
    hdu = fits.open(remote_file)
```

Comment: Yep. Long as it has a read method and returns bytes it should work.