# A way to load big data on Python from SFTP server, not using my hard disk

Tags: python, sftp

As my hard disk memory is not sufficient, I uploaded big data to SFTP server.
How can I access the server in Python and load them to analyze?
I just want to work on Python and send the output to server again, not downloading them to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

With [Paramiko library](https://www.paramiko.org/), you can use [`SFTPClient.open` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) to retrieve a file-like object that works with remote data. Most Python APIs then can use this file-like object in place of local file handle.

```
with sftp.open('filename.txt', bufsize=32768) as f:
    # use f as if you have opened a local file with open()
```

For some real-life examples, see:

- [Reading .csv file to memory from SFTP server using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56652280/850848)
- [Opening Astropy FITS file from SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53718571/850848)
- [Dump JSON files directly into a remote SSH connection without storing them in local machine first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55951860/850848)
- [Read CSV/Excel files from SFTP file, make some changes in those files using Pandas, and save back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61817226/850848)
- [Use pdfplumber and Paramiko to read a PDF file from an SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62052090/850848)
- [Transfer file from SFTP to S3 using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65787027/850848)
- [Upload file to Google bucket directly from SFTP server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70911611/850848)

---

But you will still be *downloading* the data. You cannot work with remote data locally without *downloading* them (using network bandwidth). You just won't be *storing* the data to the local file system.

---

*For the purpose of `bufsize=32768`, see [Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)*.

Answer (score -1):

Visit https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/

```
    import pysftp

    with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
        with sftp.cd('public'):             # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
        sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```

Visit http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html

Comment: oh i see.. and i got an answer i can load files when i log on through server