# Upload file to Google bucket directly from SFTP server using Python

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload file from SFTP server to GCS bucket using cloud function. But this code not working. I am able to sftp. But when I try to upload file in GCS bucket, it doesn't work, and the requirement is to use cloud function with Python.

Any help will be appreciated. Here is the sample code I am trying. This code is working except `sftp.get("test_report.csv", bucket_destination)`. Please help.

```
destination_bucket ="gs://test-bucket/reports"
with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password=sftp_password) as sftp:
    print ("Connection successfully established ... ")

    # Switch to a remote directory
    sftp.cwd('/test/outgoing/')
   
    bucket_destination = "destination_bucket"

    sftp.cwd('/test/outgoing/')
    if sftp.exists("test_report.csv"):
        sftp.get("test_report.csv", bucket_destination)
    else:
        print("doesnt exist")
```

Answer (score 2):

The pysftp cannot work with GCP directly.

Imo, you cannot actually upload a file directly from SFTP to GCP anyhow, at least not from a code running on yet another machine. But you can transfer the file without storing it on the intermediate machine, using [pysftp `Connection.open`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.open) (or better using [Paramiko `SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open)) and GCS API [`Blob.upload_from_file`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_upload_from_file). That's what many actually mean by *"directly"*.

```
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project='myproject')
bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('test_report.csv')

with sftp.open('test_report.csv', bufsize=32768) as f:
    blob.upload_from_file(f)
```

For the rest of the GCP code, see [How to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage on Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37003862/850848)

For the purpose of `bufsize`, see [Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848).

---

*Consider not using pysftp, it's dead project. Use Paramiko directly (the code will be mostly the same). See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what we built SFTP Gateway for. We have a lot of customers that still want to use SFTP, but we needed to write files directly to Google Cloud Storage. Files don't get saved temporarily on another machine. The data is streamed directly from the SFTP Client (python, filezilla, or any other client), straight to GCS.

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/thorn-technologies-public/sftp-gateway?project=thorn-technologies-public

Full disclosure, this is our product and we use it for all our consulting clients. We are happy to help you get it setup if you want to try it.

Answer (score -1):

i got the solution based on your reply thanks here is the code

```
               bucket = client.get_bucket(destination_bucket)
              `blob = bucket.blob(destination_folder +filename)

                with sftp.open(sftp_filename, bufsize=32768) as f:
                    blob.upload_from_file(f)
```

Comment: Could you share the full code, that's working? I am struggeling with the same problem...
Thank you!