# How to take data from SFTP server without downloading files in my local storage in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I have an SFTP server. I can take data by transferring/downloading files. Is there a way that I can do without downloading files?

My code is as below:

```
# Connection to the SFTP server
with pysftp.Connection(hostname, username, passowrd, port) as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('directory'):
        sftp.get('filename.txt')
```

This code downloads file to my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. You can use the data from the remote (SFTP) server without storing the files to a local disk.

But you cannot use data locally without *downloading* them. That's impossible. You have to *transfer* the data to use them – at least to a memory of the local machine.

See [A way to load big data on Python from SFTP server, not using my hard disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65655892/850848).

My answer there talks about Paramiko. But pysftp is a just a thin wrapper around Paramiko. Its [`Connection.open`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.open) is directly mapped to underlying [Paramiko's `SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open). So you can keep using pysftp:

```
with sftp.open('filename.txt', bufsize=32768) as f:
    # use f as if you have opened a local file with open()
```

Though I'd recommend you not to: [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).